# Setting div background image using JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Im using JQuery to set the background image of a div as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#pic').css("background","url(images/pic.jpg)");  

 });
```

But the image does not get displayed. How to fix this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 9):

maybe it also works with `background` but i always use

```
background-image
```

And also I always put quotes around the path

```
$('#pic').css("background-image","url('images/pic.jpg')");
```

Comment: Should work with 'background' or 'background-image'. Shouldn't be necessary to use quotes.

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it seems it is for browsers that are not IE. (+1) For Saving me hours of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Should work, but have you tried using "background-image" instead of "background"?

Also, can you navigate to the image through your browser correctly? I.e. yourdomain/images/pic.jpg?

**Edit**:
Also, have you set a width and height for the div? The div will not auto-resize for a background image.

Comment: Should work with 'background' or 'background-image'. Checking the image, by navigating to it, is always a good idea.

Comment: Good point about the width & height but, I assume, there is probably some other markup within the div that gives it height & width).

Comment: That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably down to relative path issues.

What is the path (i.e the URL that appears in the browser navigation bar) for the page that contains the code that you posted?
Where is this in relation to the images directory?

managing this can be a bit of a nightmare, especially if you've included a javascript file into multiple pages, that are at different levels within a URL hierarchy.

The better way to handle this, is to define a class, in a css file, make the image urls relative to the location of the css file itself, and then simply apply the class to your div, instead of setting individual style attributes.